# IBM ODM create a rule

Tags: rules, rule-engine, odm

I need to create a rule. I have this precondition:

- Student is adult (older than 18)
- Student's first treatment date is present and is in the past

```
if 
    the dateOfBirth of Input is before <current_date> - 18 years 
    and the firstTreatmentDate of Input is before <current_date>
then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IBM ODM Cloud, it is not possible to use the current date. If you want to use it, you should pass it in a request